# How to PUT an object in an array in MongoDB using Mongoose on form submission

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, mongodb, mongoose

My mongoDB schema looks like this:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

local            : {
    email        : String,
    password     : String,
},
userInfo         : {
    fullname     : String,
    region       : String,
},
milesLog         : []

});
```

And I have the following HTML Form:

```
   <form action="/miles" method="put">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label>Miles</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="miles">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

And I have following route:

```
  app.put('/miles', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {

        // WHAT TO DO HERE
 });
```

**Question**

***How to PUT an object containing the miles variable into the milesLog array within my user schema on form submission.***

Here's an image of my MongoDB:

[image]

So after form submission my Database should look like this:

```
 {
"_id": {
    "$oid": "54eda3160fb053cc25a9e287"
},
"userInfo": {
    "region": "Europe - UK",
    "fullname": "max26"
},
"local": {
    "password": "$2a$08$xicDozPMtIiImhwUNuV6SO0llxEnHUK3VlzNh6G7OUgbJwfoxTECC",
    "email": "max@gmail.com"
},

"milesLog: [
     {"miles": "21"},
     {"miles": "55"}
],

"__v": 0
  }
```

Thank you for your Help.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

`<form method="put">` is invalid HTML and will be treated like `<form>` ,
GET and POST are the only allowed values for the "method" attribute. if you want to use put use ajax like this :

```
$.ajax({
        url:'/miles',
        type:'PUT',
        data:{ miles : $('.form-control').val() },
        success:function(data){
           console.log('put');
        },
        error:function(err){
           console.log(err);
        }
});

//and in back-end recieve this value 
app.put('/miles', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
      var userModel = mongoose.model('User',userSchema),
          miles     = req.body.miles; //recive miles send using ajax
      userModel.update({ "userInfo.fullname" : "max26" } ,
{ $push : { 'milesLog' : { 'miles' : miles } } } , function(err , data ) {
 console.log(data);
}

});
```