# Mongoose $push from HTML Form not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong.

**My HTML Form:**

```
 <form action="/user/:id" method="put">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Miles</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="miles">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Login</button>
</form>
```

**My Express Route:**

```
  app.put('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
      User.findById(req.body.params.id, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
            console.log(user.id);

           User.findByIdAndUpdate(
                      user.id,
                      {$push: {"milesLog": {miles: req.body.miles}}},
                      {safe: true, upsert: true},

                      function(err, model) {
                      console.log(err);
                     },
                         res.json(user)

   );
```

Posting from my HTML form I get the following Error:

```
  Cannot GET /user?miles=66&activity=asdasd
```

But When I test this through POSTMAN it works:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong. Why doesn't it work from my HTML Form?**

Answer (score 0):

The route doesn't match, you have this URL

```
/user?miles=66&activity=asdasd
```

and then this route

```
app.put('/user/:id', ....
```

that route is looking for something like this

```
/user/66
```

it doesn't look for querystrings, that would be

```
app.put('/user', function(req, res) {

    var miles    = req.query.miles;
    var activity = req.query.activity;
```

and unless you have a really good reason for using `PUT` request, you should change that to use `GET` instead.

Also, `<form action="/user/:id" ...` isn't a valid URL, you can't have colons in the URL, and you seem to have misunderstood a little, the `:id` in your route matches anything, as long as it's a valid route, so it will match

```
/user/frank
/user/77
/user/something?querystring
```

etc. and then you can access that inside the route

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {

    var user = req.params.id; // returns "frank" etc
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. Basically I have an array of objects in mongoDB schema. And I want to be able to push objects into the array by submitting a form. So thats why I am using PUT. Heres a little background http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811905/how-to-put-an-object-in-an-array-in-mongodb-using-mongoose-on-form-submission                           your help is much appreciated. Thank you again.

Comment: @user2190986 - I think most browser will technically let you do a PUT request, but it's not valid, the only valid methods for a form is GET or POST, and that's what you should be using, there's no reason to use a PUT request here. Also, as noted in the answer, the route seems to be wrong and not match the URL you're using.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "PUT" verb in html forms, while you are implementing it like this:

```
 <form action="/user/:id" method="put">
```

You have to use `method="POST"` in html form and change your route to:

`app.post('/user/:id')`

It's not a bad thing to use such method.

However if you are developing a front-end application it's common to use XMLHttpRequest object which has "PUT" verb, and your route will work just fine.